# How to convert angularJS version 1.X controller into angularJS 2.X component?

Tags: angularjs, angular

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MessagesCtrl', function() {



$scope.self.list = [
    {text: 'Hello, World!'},
    {text: 'This is a message'},
    {text: 'And this is another message'}
];

self.clear = function() {
    $scope.self.list = [];
  };
});
```

Above code is in angular 1 and how can I convert this into angular 2 component?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Give me some code questions are discouraged on SO.

Answer (score 3):

There is no more concept of controllers in Angular2. So your code could be converted in this using Angular2:

- **Component definition**

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#elt of list">{{elt.text}}</li>
      </ul>
      <span (click)="clear()">Clear</span>
    `
  })
  export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
      this.list = [
        {text: 'Hello, World!'},
        {text: 'This is a message'},
        {text: 'And this is another message'}
      ];
    }

    clear() {
      this.list = [];
    }
  }
  ```
- **Component use in another one**

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
      <my-component></my-component>
    `,
    directives: [MyComponent]
  })
  export class OtherComponent {
    (...)
  }
  ```

The content of the template is very minimal since it really depends on what you want to display.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry